# CQRS Where to Query for business logic/Internal Processes

Tags: events, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm currently looking at implementing CQRS driven by events (not yet event sourcing) in for a service at work; the reasoning being:

- I need aggregate data to support a RestAPI coming out of this service (which will be used to populate views)- however the aggregated data will not be used by the application logic/processing (ie the data originating outside this service, the bits that of the aggregate originating within it will be used)
- I need to stream events to other systems so that they can react to the data (will produce to a Kafka topic, so the 'read'/'projection' side of this system will consume the same events as the external systems, from these Kafka topics
- I will be consuming events from internal systems to help populate the aggregate for the views in first point (ie it's data from this service and other's)

The reason for not going event sourced currently is that a) we're in a bit of a time crunch, and b) due to still learning about it. Having said which, it is something that we are looking to do in the future- though currently, we have a static DB in the 'Command' side of the system, which will just store current state

I'm pretty confident with the concept of using the aggregate data to provide the Rest API; however my confusion is coming from when I want to change a resource from within the system (for example via a cron job triggered 5 times a day) Example:

- If I have resource of class x, which (given some data), wants a piece of state changing
- I need to select instances of the class x which meet the requirements (from one of the DB's). Think  `select * from {class x} where last_changed_ date > 5 days ago;`
- Then create a command to change the state of these instances of x (in my case, the static command DB would be updated, as well as an event made to update the read DB)

The middle bullet point is what is confusing me. If I pull the data out of the Read DB, and check some information on it, then decide to change a property; I then have to convert the object from the 'Read Object' to the 'Command Object', so that I can then persist it and create an event? With my current architecture- I could query the command DB no problem, to find all the instances of {class x} that match the criteria, however I don't know if a) this is the right thing to do, and b) how this would work if I was using an event store as a DB? I'd have to query a table with millions of rows to find the most recent bit of state about the objects, to then see if they match?

Lots of what I read online has been very conceptual- so I think when it comes to implementations it maybe seems more difficult than it is? Anyhow, if anyone has any advice it would be hugely appreciated!

TIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQRS can be interpreted in a "permissive" way: rather than saying "thou shalt not query the command/write side", it says "it's OK to have a query/read side that's separate from the command/write side".  Because you have this permission to do such separation, it follows that one can optimize the command/write side for a more write-heavy workload (in practice, there are always some reads in the command/write side: since command validation is typically done against some state, that requires some means of getting the state!).  From this, it's extremely likely that there will be some queries which can be performed efficiently against the command/write side and some that can't be (without deoptimizing the command/write side).  From this perspective, it's OK to perform the first kind of query against the command/write side: you can get the benefit of strong consistency by doing that, though be sure to make sure that you're not affecting the command/write side's primary *raison d'etre* of taking writes.

Event sourcing is in many ways the maximally optimized persistence model for a command/write side, especially if you have some means of keeping the absolute latest state cached and ensuring concurrency control.  This is because you can then have many times more writes than reads.  The tradeoff in event sourcing is that nearly all reads become rather more expensive than in an update-in-place model: it's thus generally the case that CQRS doesn't force event sourcing but event sourcing tends to force CQRS (and in turn, event sourcing can simplify ensuring that a CQRS system is eventually consistent, which can be difficult to ensure with update-in-place).

In an event-sourced system, you would tend to have a read-side which subscribes to the event stream and tracks the mapping of `X ID` to `last updated` and which periodically queries and issues commands.  Alternatively, you can have a scheduler service that lets you say "issue this command at this time, unless canceled or rescheduled before then" and a read-side which subscribes to updates and schedules a command for the given ID 5 days from now after canceling the command from the previous update.